# Android 3 Layers Layout with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to have a layout with 3 layers. I'm using 3 linearlayouts in which one of it is an listview, but my bottom Linearlayout does not appear on screen.

I need:
On Top: Horizontal Linear Layout | On Center: Listview | On Bottom: Horizontal Linear Layout

I'm using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/titleBgColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filterButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/filtericon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"
            style="@style/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="(blank)" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCatButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/effect_button_add_cat_click" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_style_list_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/titleBgColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/optionsButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/filtericon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalValue"
            style="@style/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="66,00€" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savExpIncValues"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/effect_button_add_cat_click" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong? thanks

Comment: what ur logcat shows?

Comment: paste your java code along with your logcat trace,i think it will help to understan ur question

Comment: ok. i figured out what was forcing close. but now the problem is other. My bottom layout is not shown on screen. I have my top layout, the listview on the center but not the bottom layout. I edited the code above without the "Force Close" error

Comment: set all layouts android:height="wrap_content" and then give it a shot

Comment: didnt worked. it became all messed up

Comment: i think its because of your last linear layout,change anroid:orentation="vertical" and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the layout for you. Give it a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/titleBgColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/filterButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/filtericon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"
            style="@style/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="(blank)" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCatButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/effect_button_add_cat_click" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_style_list_selector"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/titleBgColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/optionsButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/filtericon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalValue"
            style="@style/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="66,00€" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savExpIncValues"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/effect_button_add_cat_click" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of your second layout is set as match_parent, change it to wrap_content or with a fixed size. But I strongly suggest that you use the weight properties to set the height of the 3 layouts in this way:

```
    <!-- your first layout -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="35dp"... >
    ... 
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- your second layout -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
    ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- your third layout -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="35dp" ..>
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also set all the LinearLayout orientation to vertical.

Comment: ive done that and now i have the top layout first, bottom layout second and no list view. Without that change i had top layout first, listview second and no bottom layout.